# the suggested search terms still display (with display_in_terms =0) below the search textfield

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch

My Magento website search bar displays the suggested search terms still display (with display_in_terms =0) below the search text field.

How can I fix the problem? Is it a bug of Magento 1.8.1?

Comment: I think you should add some more detail to the error, may be screenshot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Query\collection.php
just add in lines 126

```
    $this->getSelect()->where('display_in_terms = 1');
```

it OK.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer though I would suggest not rewriting the core code.

Comment: Modifying core files is strongly in conflict with Magento best practices.